# Do you think that Goat theme is good for a qa site?

Tags: theme

I'm going to open a question-answer web site however I was unable to find a good domain name. And it is non-English, by the way. So, I thought to have a theme; goats, kinda goatasks. And there will be goat logo with "waving" tail, and after you ask a question you will hear goat sound. Do you think that it is a good idea?

Comment: I have nothing against goats personally, but the part about playing a sound after you ask a question is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: I can't speak for the goats, but I do think this question is a little too localized for this site :)

Answer (score 2):

No, I'd go with "bananas". "Ask a banana". "Ask a goat" sounds silly, as if goats could talk and answer questions.